# Spring-SAML Authentication Failed: HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT

Tags: authentication, spring-security, saml-2.0, opensaml, spring-saml

I'm using spring-saml2-sample app to connect to a Shibboleth IDP. I finally managed to send the correct saml request to the IDP using http post, but after login I get back the following on the SP side:

org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT

There was a post like this one where the problem was resolved by moving to spring security version 3.1.2, but that is the version that comes with the saml2-sample app. 
Am I missing something? I haven't changed much in the saml2-sample app, the web.xml is the same, libs are the same.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you working with the sample application or are you integration Spring SAML into your own? Can you make the codebase available?

Comment: Thank you Vladimir for your reply. I was looking at the wrong place in the debug, my problem was that I had default as alias in the SP  metadata and in securityContext I had defaultAlias as alias.